# Getting values in joomla component controller function

Tags: php, joomla, components

I am facing  issue (as i am relatively new to Joomla Component Development) regarding how to pass values between two functions in a my Joomla Custom Component's controller.php

Below is my controller.php file

```
 <?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/googlemaps/navigation.js');
/**
 * Hello World Component Controller
 */
class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    function display(){
   echo '<form action="'. echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloworld&controller=helloworld&task=displayData') .'" method="post">';
   echo '<h1>This is Insert Task</h1><br><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br>';
   echo '<input type="text" id="surname" value="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">';
   echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">'; 
   echo '</form>';
    }

    function delete(){
        $id=JRequest::getVar('id');
        echo "You want to delete $id";
    }

    function displayData(){

        $name=JRequest::getVar('name');
        $surname=JRequest::getVar('surname');
        //$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
        //$stateVar = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest( "$option.state_variable", "surname", "Hello" );
        echo "Your name is $name and surname is $surname";
        //**How can i get the name and surname variables here after the page refreshes and this task loads**
    }
}
```

I have two form fields in the Display() task of controller and i want to get the values i enter in those fields in another task below named displayData().
The only way i figured out is using the post method of form and getting the variables via $_POST[ ] method. Joomla provides user state and variables and all that stuff but i m not able to figure out how to use them here.

Comment: Are you working in 1.5? Is there a reason you can't use the current apis? Also there is a whole built in api for googlemaps you might want to look at that.

Comment: Wait you can't be in 1.5 but why are you using JRequest?

Comment: I am using Joomla 2.5 and the i am sorry but i could not figure out another way to transfer data between two tasks in controller (or its different views) other then JRequest.
And about that googlemaps inbuilt api by joomla...can you provide me any link regarding that ?

Comment: JRequest is deprecated, use JInput instead. http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput.  For the API it is in your libraries folder `libraries/joomla/google/embed/maps.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i have noticed you form does have form tag therefore it can not send data to server.Change the code as follows.

```
    function display(){
       echo '<form action="'. echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloworld&controller=helloworld&task=displayData') .'" method="post">';
       echo '<h1>This is Insert Task</h1><br><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br>';
       echo '<input type="text" id="surname" value="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">';
       echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">'; 
       echo '</form>';       
    }
```

Note you can use MVC for much clarity. MVC is a form of arranging you code for better development and debugging. You can create the following structure.

- com_helloworld

  - controllers

    - helloworld.php
  - models

    - helloworld.php
  - views

    - helloworld

      - view.html.php
      - tmpl

        - default.php

  Under com_helloworld->controllers->helloworld.php put this.

  ```
   <?php
  // No direct access to this file
  defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

  // import Joomla controller library
  jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
  JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/googlemaps/navigation.js');
  /**
   * Hello World Component Controller
   */
  class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
  {

      function delete(){
          $id=JRequest::getVar('id');
          echo "You want to delete $id";
      }
      function displayData(){
          // LOAD THE MODEL AND DO PROCESSING THERE
          // $model = $this->getModel();

          $name=JRequest::getVar('name');
          //$surname=JRequest::getVar('surname');
          //$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
          //$stateVar = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.state_variable", "surname", "Hello" );
          echo "Your name is $name and surname is $surname";
          //**How can i get the name and surname variables here after the page refreshes and this task loads**
     }

  }
  ```

Under com_helloworld->view->tmpl->default.php put this.

```
    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloworld&controller=helloworld&task=displayData') ?>" method="post">
    <h1>This is Insert Task</h1><br><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="text" id="surname" value="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dedan for the pointers...i have been successful already in the way you described above..sorry about the code posted, i have modified it. I just want to make sure that this is the correct and best way to pass data between two pages.
What about the user state variables and all that ?